# Why my prog can't run correctly?

Tags: c++

[image]// Calculate the quarters of a set of integers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::sort;

int main()
{
 // Ask for a set of integers
 cout << "Please input a set of integers: "
   << endl;

 // Read the set of integers
  // x is the variable to write
 int x;
  // int_set is the set of integers to write
 vector<int> int_set;
 while (cin >> x)
  {
   int_set.push_back(x);
  }

 // Check if the integer set is vacant 
 typedef std::vector<int>::size_type vec_sz;
 vec_sz size = int_set.size();
 if (size == 0)
  cout << "There are no data. "
    << "Please try again. ";

 // Sort
 sort (int_set.begin(), int_set.end());

 // The set of integers multiply 1/4
 vector<double> int_set_quarter;
 cout << "The quarters of the set of integers are: ";
 for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i)
  {
   int_set_quarter[i] = 1/4 * int_set[i];
   cout << int_set_quarter[i]; 
   cout << endl;
  }

    getch();
 return 0;
}
```

If you run, then it will collapse...

Comment: By the way - if you bothered to conduct a primitive debugging session, you would have found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int_set_quarter`'s size is 0 and you index on it.
Change

```
vector<double> int_set_quarter;
```

to

```
vector<double> int_set_quarter(size);
```

Comment: @Eric: What do you mean: how to fix it out? if you change the lines as I said, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
vector<double> int_set_quarter;
int_set_quarter[0] = 0.25;
```

This code will crash, because the `int_set_quarter` vector does not have a 0th element. You already know how to fix this (you used the same thing in your `int_set` vector). You add elements to the end of a vector with the `push_back` method. You can also use Armen's method of setting up the size of the vector initially via it's constructor.

But in this specific example, you don't need that. You never actually use the `int_set_quarter` vector, so you can just do this:

```
// The set of integers multiply 1/4
cout << "The quarters of the set of integers are: ";
for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i)
{
    double quarter = 1/4 * int_set[i];
    cout << quarter; 
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements to a vector the way you're trying to do with `int_set_quarter`, so you end up writing to somewhere that hasn't been allocated yet. This causes an access violation, and your program crashes.

You can either reserve the necessary space in the vector by providing the number of required elements when [creating the vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/), by calling [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) or [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/), or by using [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) to add the element to the end of the vector...

...or, since you don't do anything with `int_set_quarter` after the loop, you can just calculate what you need to output for that iteration into a local variable, sa shown by [Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948658/why-my-prog-cant-run-correctly/3948678#3948678).